# Nginx: rename URL after a redirection

Tags: nginx

My new website's address is `foo.pro`, when I go my old website `bar.pro`, it shows the content of the new `foo.pro` as expected but the URL remains `bar.pro`.

How to replace `bar.pro` by `foo.pro` in my Nginx configuration below ?

```
upstream foo_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3003;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {

    server_name www.foo.pro;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://foo_upstream;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.foo.pro/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.foo.pro/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = www.foo.pro) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name www.foo.pro;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  foo.pro;
    return 301 https://www.foo.pro;
}
```

**=== EDIT ===**

I tried to add this directive in my conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  bar.pro;
    return 301 https://foo.pro;
}
```

But it's still not renaming the URL to `foo.pro`.

Comment: What's the configuration for the old website `bar.pro`? If there isn't one, you need to add a configuration for `bar.pro` and make it redirect to `foo.pro`, using a `return 301` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith There is no configuration for `bar.pro`, what would it look like ? I need a redirection for any `http(s)://*.bar.pro/*` to `foo.pro`.

Comment: It could look (almost) identical to your existing `server` blocks, except with `return 301 https://www.foo.pro$request_uri;` instead of the `location /` block.